# Can't get nuget working from command line on travis

Tags: .net, f#, nuget, travis-ci

I'm back to trying to get some F# project to be build-able with Travis-ci

- github project: https://github.com/Heather/Failess/blob/master/.travis.yml

yml:

```
language: objective-c

env:
 global:
  - EnableNuGetPackageRestore=true 
 matrix:
  - MONO_VERSION="3.2.6"

before_install:
 - wget "http://download.xamarin.com/MonoFrameworkMDK/Macx86/MonoFramework-MDK-${MONO_VERSION}.macos10.xamarin.x86.pkg"
 - sudo installer -pkg "MonoFramework-MDK-${MONO_VERSION}.macos10.xamarin.x86.pkg" -target /
 - mozroots --import --sync

script:
 - mono "packages\\NuGet\\NuGet.exe" install Failess -OutputDirectory packages -ExcludeVersion -Prerelease
 - mono "packages\\Failess\\tools\\Failess.exe" "build.fsx"
```

But even nuget fails here:

- travis: https://travis-ci.org/Heather/Failess/builds/19554098

  $ mono "packages\NuGet\NuGet.exe" install Failess -OutputDirectory packages -ExcludeVersion -Prerelease

> ```
>  ApplicationName='/Users/travis/.local/share/NuGet/NuGet.exe', CommandLine='install Failess -OutputDirectory packages -ExcludeVersion
> -Prerelease'
> , CurrentDirectory='/Users/travis/build/Heather/Failess'
> , Native error= Cannot find the specified file The command "mono "packages\NuGet\NuGet.exe" install Failess -OutputDirectory packages
> -ExcludeVersion -Prerelease" exited with 1.
> ```

what's wrong with it?

Comment: I am no expert on Travis, but I was able to get my project to build with unit tests on Travis. I don't know if it makes a difference but I didn't have quotes in my nuget call.  ``if [ ! -f packages/FAKE/tools/Fake.exe ]; then
  mono --runtime=v4.0 .NuGet/NuGet.exe install FAKE -OutputDirectory packages -ExcludeVersion -Prerelease
``  For reference my .travis.yml file is at : https://github.com/mndrake/Arcadia/blob/master/.travis.yml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So slashes don't matter, running inside a shell script doesn't matter, I think what you have should work.

The problem is that version of `NuGet.exe` checked into your repository is some old version of nuget that isn't mono compatible. Download the newest version from https://nuget.org/nuget.exe or you can use `NuGet.exe update --self` if the version of nuget you have supports it.